# In zsh for loop, zero-leading number string generation

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have many part-00001, part-00002, ... files.

I want to use this way:

```
for ((i=0;i<1000;i++)); do <some command> <formatted string with i>; done.
```

How can I format "part-000xx"-like string with number i in zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done with:

- `typeset -Z 5 i` (using builtin `typeset -Z [N]`)
- `printf "part-%05d" $i` (using builtin `printf "%05d" $i`)
- `${(l:5::0:)i}` (using parameter expansion flags `l:expr::string1:string2:`)

like below:

```sh
    typeset -Z 5 j
    for ((i=0;i<1000;i++)); do
      # <some command> <formatted string with i>
      j=$i; echo "part-$j" # use $j here for sure the effects of below 2 lines
      echo "$(printf "part-%05d" $i)"
      echo "part-${(l:5::0:)j}"
    done
    # This outputs below:
    # >> part-00000
    # >> part-00000
    # >> part-00000
    # >> part-00001
    # >> part-00001
    # >> part-00001
    # >> ...
    # >> part-00999
```

Here is the description for each item.

---

> `typeset`
>   `-Z` [N]
>   Specially handled if set along with the -L flag. Otherwise, similar to -R, except that leading zeros are used for padding instead of blanks if the first non-blank character is a digit. Numeric parameters are specially handled: they are always eligible for padding with zeroes, and the zeroes are inserted at an appropriate place in the output.
>   -- [`zshbuiltins(1)`, `typeset`, Shell Builtin Commands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-typeset)

---

> `printf`
>    Print the arguments according to the format specification. Formatting rules are the same as used in C.
>   -- [`zshubuiltins(1)`, `printf`, Shell Builtin Commands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-printf)

---

> `l`*:expr::string1::string2:*
>   Pad the resulting words on the left. Each word will be truncated if required and placed in a field *expr* characters wide.
>   The arguments *:string1:* and *:string2:* are optional; neither, the first, or both may be given. Note that the same pairs of delimiters must be used for each of the three arguments. The space to the left will be filled with *string1* (concatenated as often as needed) or spaces if string1 is not given. If both *string1* and *string2* are given, *string2* is inserted once directly to the left of each word, truncated if necessary, before string1 is used to produce any remaining padding.
>   -- [`zshexpn(1)`, Parameter Expansion Flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-flags_002c-parameter-expansion)

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.